# "Hari's desire will be better" - A Tale

Tags: vishnu

In Gujarat as well as other states like Maharashtra there is a tale " Hari ichcha bhali hashe" or "Hari's will shall be for good." What is the reason/myth/story behind that?

Comment: It is equivalent to "Let Thy will be done"

Comment: It is a corruption of Sanskrit ईश्वरेच्छा बलीयसी, which means God's will is powerful (than everything else). It seems it somehow got distorted into "bhali", which means good.

Comment: @AmitSaxena, a small correction - 'Let Thy will be done' is equivalent to that tale, because Bible came later :)